# Laravel redirect when already logged in

Tags: php, laravel

**Basic Info :**

Using Laravel 7.29.3

All my routes need a locale based on the chosen language by the user. A valid URL looks like
this [www.test.com/en/home](http://www.test.com/en/home) for example

**Situation :**

A user has my website opened in two Tabs  , Tab1 and Tab2. Same website in both Tabs.

He's logging in using Tab1 and gets authenticated. Then he clicks the Login Button in Tab2.
Laravel realises the user is already authenticated and redirects the user to [www.test.com/home](http://www.test.com/home).

The Problem is that [www.test.com/home](http://www.test.com/home) doesn't have any locale in it and is invalid. User get's a 404 error.

In the Laravel LoginController there is a variable

```
 protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;
```

But how do I get the currently chosen language locale in there ? I know the function
app()->getLocale() but when I try

```
protected $redirectTo = app()->getLocale() . RouteServiceProvider::HOME;
```

I get an Error saying

```
Constant expression contains invalid operations
```

I've already added the following function to my LoginController but Laravel ignores it in the above mentioned situation with Two Tabs.

```
protected function redirectTo()
{

return app()->getLocale() . '/home';

}
```

So how can I get the currently chosen locale / language in redirectTo ?

```
 protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This is my first reply ever so sorry if doesn't help you but I think in laravel 7 you have a method located in AuthenticatesUsers trait that is called authenticated() this may help you perform you desired action after the user is logged in or just create a method redirectPath() in your controller to override it from RedirectsUsers if redirectTo() function is not fired.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I added the following functions to my LoginController but still get the error public function authenticated()
 {
  
  
  return redirect(route('home', app()->getLocale()));
  
 }
 
 public function redirectPath(){
  
 return redirect(route('home', app()->getLocale())); 
  
 }

Comment: Try this and remove authenticated()
    public function redirectPath()
    {
        return app()->getLocale() . '/home';
    }. I just tried the function on my logincontroller and redirects the user to www.example.com/en/home.  The redirectPath() function must return the desired url. If you check your sendLoginResponse(), you will see that it is already called redirect(), you dont need to call it again.

Comment: 'code'    public function redirectPath()
    {
        return app()->getLocale() . '/home';
    } 'code'

Comment: I found the problem. I had to edit the Middleware RedirectIfAuthenticated.php . I replaced the line return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME); by return redirect(route('home', app()->getLocale()));   Now it works.

Comment: Yes. I didnt read your question well. You didnt have the problem when the user logged in, but when the user was already logged. I see. My bad. I am happy that you solved your problem.

Comment: Thanks anyway you guided me in the right direction.